# MySQL: Case Query within a Case Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that gets unit count and it tagging if completed or not.

```
SELECT distinct location, 
case when  id is NULL then 'Not Started'
 when '1'  then 'Completed' 
 else 'In Progress' end   as Remarks,
count(name) as CountName
FROM table
group by location,
case when  id is NULL then 'Not Started'
 when '1'  then 'Completed' 
 else 'In Progress' end;
```

**Result:**

[image]

But I want to summarized this as below image:

[image]

Condition is when there are more that two(2) Remarks in Location it should be tagged as "In-progress" and sum the CountName. But when only one Remarks for a Location, gets the Remarks as its tagged.

Comment: I assume when you said: *when there are __more that__ two(2) Remarks*, you actually meant: *__at least__ two (2)*.

Comment: btw, in your query, where you do `when '1'`, it should really be `when id = '1'`, otherwise, it doesn't work as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, a case within a case:

```
select location,
       case when count(distinct case when id is null then 'Not Started'
                                     when id = '1' then 'Completed'
                                     else 'In Progress' end) > 1
            then 'In Progress'
            else max(case when id is null then 'Not Started'
                          when id = '1' then 'Completed'
                          else 'In Progress' end)
        end as remarks,
        count(*) as CountName
  from tbl
 group by location
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da44c/1)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did @Joel's answer not work as well?  At first I didn't understand it, but once I did, I thought his answer was clever and much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure on this (sample data would help), but try this:

```
SELECT Location, 
    case when count(id) > 1 then 'In Progress'
         when max(id) is null then 'Not Started'
         when max(id) = 1 then 'Completed'
         else 'In Progress' end As Remarks,
    count(name) as CountName
FROM table
GROUP BY location
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This query:-

```
SELECT location, 
       if(count(1) > 1, 'In Progress', Remarks) Remarks, 
       sum(countName) countName 
   FROM location 
   group by location
```